# template static member vector of template structs (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, vector, static-members

I think this code will explain itself better than I can with english:

```
namespace SC
{
struct GraphicalDatumBase
{
    struct SwitcherBase
    {
        virtual void switchBuffers(){}
    };

    static std::vector<SwitcherBase*> switchers;

    static void switchBuffers();

    virtual void update(){}
};

template<class Datum>
struct GraphicalDatum: public GraphicalDatumBase
{
    GraphicalDatum(Datum& originalDatum):
        originalDatum(originalDatum)
    {
        for(; doubleBufferIndex < doubleBuffers.size(); ++doubleBufferIndex)
        {
            if(doubleBuffers[doubleBufferIndex].isVacant)
            {
                doubleBuffers[doubleBufferIndex].occupy(originalDatum);
                return;
            }
        }

        doubleBuffers.emplace_back(originalDatum);
    }


    Datum& datum(){ return doubleBuffers[doubleBufferIndex].readBuffer(); }

    void update()
    {
        doubleBuffers[doubleBufferIndex].writeBuffer() = originalDatum;
        doubleBuffersToBeSwitched.push_back(doubleBufferIndex);
    }

private:

    struct DoubleBuffer
    {
        struct
        {
            uint8_t bufferSwitch:   1;
            uint8_t isVacant:       1;
        };

        Datum buffer0;
        Datum buffer1;

        DoubleBuffer(const Datum& original):
            bufferSwitch(0),
            isVacant(0),
            buffer0(original),
            buffer1(original){}

        void occupy(const Datum& original)
        {
            bufferSwitch = 0;
            isVacant = 0;
            buffer0 = original;
        }

        Datum& readBuffer(){ return (bufferSwitch? buffer1 : buffer0); }
        Datum& writeBuffer(){ return (bufferSwitch? buffer0 : buffer1); }

        void switchBuffer(){ bufferSwitch = !bufferSwitch; }
    };

    struct Switcher: public SwitcherBase
    {
        Switcher()
        {
            switchers.emplace_back(this);
        }

        void switchBuffers()
        {
            for(uint32_t d = 0; d < doubleBuffersToBeSwitched.size(); ++d)
            {
                doubleBuffers[doubleBuffersToBeSwitched[d]].switchBuffer();
            }
            doubleBuffersToBeSwitched.clear();
        }
    };

    static Switcher switcher;

    static std::vector<DoubleBuffer> doubleBuffers;
    static std::vector<uint32_t> doubleBuffersToBeSwitched;

    void switchBuffers();

    Datum& originalDatum;

    int32_t doubleBufferIndex = 0;
};

template<class Datum>
std::vector<GraphicalDatum<Datum>::DoubleBuffer> GraphicalDatum<Datum>::doubleBuffers;

...
```

The last line, where I try to define `doubleBuffers`, produces (in gcc) these errors:

```
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
  expected a type, got ‘SC::GraphicalDatum<Datum>::DoubleBuffer’
template argument 2 is invalid
```

My impression is that the compiler has a problem using a template as the vector's template argument.  Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Global variables, which they basically are, are bad anyway. You probably need a typename keyword in there.

Comment: I just tried using `template<typename Datum>` instead of `class`, but nothing changed.

Comment: `typename grapgicaldatum<datum>::doublebuffer`

Comment: re: Neil Kirk:  I'm trying to figure out how to put `DoubleBuffer` in a typename and use that in the vector, is that what you meant?  I've never had to use the typename keyword like this before, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: I don't have a compiler handy, sometimes you need it to tell it you have a type dependant on a templates type.

Comment: Okay thanks - the line `std::vector<typename GraphicalDatum<Datum>::DoubleBuffer> GraphicalDatum<Datum>::doubleBuffers;` worked.  I'll accept if you put it in an answer.

Comment: Let's just assume this compiles.  What do you think will happen when you include the template in multiple source files and start using it?  Multiple local instances of a static is what I expect would happen.

Comment: @paddy Then you expect wrong. By definition, there is only one instance of the static variable.